# Focus change on control Autoit

Tags: autoit

I have a application window with two text fields (no access to the application code, so cant change anything). User scans a barcode in the fields, the action "enter press" is programmed in the scanner and cannot be changed. I need to validate the fields before enter is pressed, I can validate the first field but the issue is I need to validate the second field before enter is press(which is through the scanner). Is there a way this can be achieved using AutoIT? I hope the question make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "AutoIt v2 Window Info" tool (Au3Info.exe) to identify the two edit controls. On the "Control" tab you find the "Advanced Mode", which will show data like "[CLASS:Edit;INSTANCE:2]". Now use this information to read the data of the control:

```
$Text1 = ControlGetText('window title', '', '[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]')
$Text2 = ControlGetText('window title', '', '[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:2]')
```

See the example here: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlGetText.htm

Answer (score 1):

most barcode scanners can be programmed to not send the terminator (enter) usually by scanning a couple special barcodes in the users manual
I program scanners with special terminators so our program can tell the input was from a scanner and not key presses